# Timing Each Element of a Script

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I have been working on this script for a long time, but the code takes about 300ms to execute, which is a little longer than I am happy with, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to time the script, but how long each event takes.

I was thinking of putting a timer function before and after each line, but given the size of the code, this would take forever.

If anyone knows of any tools, then that would be great.

N.B.
A while ago I remember reading something on php.net about a PHP call that would run another function every so many procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool to profile your code.

Take a look at the [xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/)'s [profiling features](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

This will allow you to visualize the time taken by each function, how many times it's called, its callers and callees, etc.

---

I think what you read about was related to [ticks](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php): http://www.freeopenbook.com/phpcookbook/phpckbk-chp-8-sect-26.html

Comment: cheers and cheers, thats very useful man, plus the function i was looking for was register_tick_function but that link you commented was far better, thanks man